# .net Core service accessing serialport from remotedesktop session

Tags: iis, windows-services, remote-desktop, .net-core-3.1

I have a .net core 3.1 service running that is using a custom Com dll that is talking to a machine connected on a serial port(serial to usb cable). The service is hosted on a windows 2012 server. 
A user is then opening a remote desktop session to the server and forwarding the local serial port where the machine is connected to. When we run the service as a service the custom Com dll cant talk to the forwarded port, but if we run the service as a standalone, not as a service, (kestrel) session inside the remote desktop session it works fine.
Cant a windows service(or IIS service) communicate with a serialport that is forwarded using remote desktop port forward? is the port only available in that "session" and not accessable from the service context?

We have tried to run the service as the current users, local system, network system etc.. we have tried to run the service hosted in IIS and regular window service, we also tried to run it as a scheduled task but with same result.

Anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you view any error message from your application or event viewer?

Comment: No no messages in eventviewer, application messages only give an error message from the Com dll saying it cant access the comport